# Audio stream node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, audio

I need help, in dont know how to search information for my particular case. I explain:

I need to develop a process which receives audio files provided by a MySQL database. These files I want to play and they are captured by a hardware called "BARIX".

I have problems in finding information to play audio locally without using the browser. All the information I find is related to play in the browser, you can not play audio for instance via socket?

The hardware "BARIX" urls will look, I may have a radio (http url), a real time protocol(RTP) or an m3u file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Barix makes a lot of gear.  What specific hardware are you using?  It isn't clear to me what you are trying to do.  You're trying to play a stream from a Barix encoder?  Or the other way around?

Comment: Hi Brad, i have the new Barix Exstreamer 105 and now he only is a client.

Comment: I have a N files of audio that i need to play them in some hours, as announces (PA). Me new Barix ( only client ) can listen by url (radio, rtp, or m3u file) and i need to develop an node module for play this audio files and put the url where the audio is played.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the mic npm and the sox-async npm which are audio stream wrappers requires you to install SOX Sound Xchange on the server so the mic and sox-async npm can interact/manipulate audio and stream.

SOX (MAC/WINDOWS) , if you have LINUX use ARECORD .

Hope this helps to get you started working with audio files and mic and audio streams.

Comment: Where possible include in your answers code samples or shell commands. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer